# JOIN after WHERE clause in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am performing a query in which desirable output is first apply where clause then after I want to perform right join.I have this query but it perform first join then where.thank you for you any help advance.

Here is my query

```
$friends = friend_list::where('friend_lists.user_id', '=', $id)
                        ->rightJoin('users as u1', 'u1.id', '=', 'friend_lists.user_id2')
                        ->where('friend_lists.user_id2','!=',$id)                    
                        ->where('u1.id','!=',$id)
                        ->orwhere('status',null)
                        ->get();
```

edited:
I am implementing friend request section.
In which user table contains...user(id,name,..,..) friend_list(userid,userid2,status)
in `friend_list` shows status with other friend.I do right join with`friend_list`.if status  is `null` then there is no row for that user with current user.so status is null and it shows `add friend`
.so null value is important therefor right join with `user table`

Comment: Can you please let me know what kind of data do you need? And what is your database structure?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: The sql statements don't get executed in the order that you write them as far as I'm aware.

Comment: yes I want first where then after join but doesn't happening

Comment: You cannot compare  like this `->orwhere('status',null)` for **NULL** value. For that you must use this `->orwhereNotNull('status').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the WHERE to another JOIN condition

```
$friends = friend_list::rightJoin('users as u1', function($join) {
         $join->on('u1.id', '=', 'friend_lists.user_id2')
              ->where('friend_lists.user_id', '=', $id);
     })
    ->where('friend_lists.user_id2','!=',$id)                    
    ->where('u1.id','!=',$id)
    ->orwhere('status',null)
    ->get();
```